# Access row properties dynamically

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres in the Version 9.3;

I have a 2dim Array like this:

```
DECLARE
categories varchar [][] := array[
            ['Running', 'Hiking', 'InlineSkating', ... , 'Wintersports'],
            ['GoingOutTogether', 'GoingForDrinks', ..., 'GoingForAWalk'],
            ['GettingMessages', ... , 'Gifts'],
            ['Wellness', ... 'WashingCars'],
            ['Ironing', ... 'TechnicalSupport']
        ];
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM "Users" WHERE "Id" <> sender_object."Id" LOOP

        -- ???

    END LOOP;
END;
```

The Strings in there are the names of my colums in the table "Users". How can I iterate through them and get the value of the User row. When I use something like row."Running" then I get the value I want. Any idea how I can do it?

Comment: Do you really have all those attributes as columns of the `users` table? You probably want to look at the `hstore` datatype which is much better at storing dynamic attributes.

Comment: hstore seems to be a good idea, but I have got about 70-80 colums and they dont change (most of them are booleans). These are just split into 5 categories (therefore I have got an array like you can see above). I just wanted to make it this way, because otherwise I would need to make 70-80 If/Else Statements in my calculations later on, since I need basically to compare 2 rows each column and calculate some values out of it

Comment: You can convert your row to a hstore using `hstore("Users")` inside the select statement. Then you can access the column values dynamically.